# 日本語に違和感: トップバーのヘルプメニュー

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

**現状:**

```
次に戻る: スタック・オーバーフロー
メイン サイトに戻る

ツアー
サイトの簡単な概要はここから開始

ヘルプ センター
あなたの質問に対する詳細な回答

メタとは?
メタとメイン サイトの違い

メタ
このサイトの構成とポリシーに関するディスカッションに参加
```

<sub>「メタ」メニューはメインサイトでヘルプメニューを開いた時に表示されます。</sub>

**原文**

```
Back to Stack Overflow
Return to the main site

Tour
Start here for a quick overview of the site

Help Center
Detailed answers to any questions you might have

What's Meta?
How Meta is different from the main site

Meta
Discuss the workings and policies of this site
```

**大きな違和感がある箇所:**

- 「次に戻る」
- 「ヘルプセンター」の説明: あなたの質問に対する詳細な回答

**より自然にできる箇所:**

- 「ツアー」の説明: サイトの簡単な概要はここから開始
- 「メタ」の説明: このサイトの構成とポリシーに関するディスカッションに参加

**スクリーンショット:**

[image: ヘルプメニュー]

Comment: 遅くなって申し訳ありませんでした！次回のビルドに適用します。

Answer (score 1):

```
スタック・オーバーフローに戻る
メインサイトに戻ります

ツアー
はやわかりツアーはこちらから

ヘルプ
どんな質問でもお答えします

メタとは?
メタとメインサイトの違いについて

メタ
コミュニティの運営について
```

Comment: ヘルプセンターについてですが、数多くな箇所に使っています。ヘルプセンターには違和感ありますか？そして、「次のサイトに戻る：」は現在適用できないので、開発者に頼んで、少々時間がかかります。

Comment: @jmac ヘルプセンターでokだと思います。違和感はとくにないです